# Maintaining order when indexing into Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

If I have a Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex, how can I index into the DataFrame while preserving the order of the things I indexed with?

For example, if I create a DataFrame with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    ("alice", "us", 5),
    ("alice", "fr", 10),
    ("alice", "de", 15),
    ("bob", "us", 10),
    ("bob", "de", 20),
    ("bob", "fr", 15),
    ("charlie", "za", 20),
    ("charlie", "de", 5),
    ("charlie", "us", 10),
], columns=["name", "country", "value"])

df.set_index(["name", "country"], inplace=True)
```

then `df` contains:

```
                 value
name    country
alice   us           5
        fr          10
        de          15
bob     us          10
        de          20
        fr          15
charlie za          20
        de           5
        us          10
```

If I then index into it to get values where `name` is "charlie" or "alice", and `country` is "de", "us", or "za", and then print the results as tuples:

```
for t in df.loc[(["charlie", "alice"], ["de", "us", "za"]), :].itertuples():
    print(t)
```

then I get the results in the index's sort order, rather than the order of the lists I used to index with, i.e.:

```
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'us'), value=5)
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'de'), value=15)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'za'), value=20)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'de'), value=5)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'us'), value=10)
```

How can I do something similar, but maintain the order I indexed with? E.g. I'd like the output to be:

```
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'de'), value=5)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'us'), value=10)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'za'), value=20)
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'de'), value=15)
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'us'), value=5)
```

i.e. in the same order as the values I used in `df.loc[(["charlie", "alice"], ["de", "us", "za"]), :]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `reindex` with the `MultiIndex.from_product` made with your two lists. You need to `dropna` to not get rows that did not exist before.

```
for t in (df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["charlie", "alice"], 
                                                 ["de", "us", "za"])))
           .dropna().itertuples()):
    print(t)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'de'), value=5.0)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'us'), value=10.0)
Pandas(Index=('charlie', 'za'), value=20.0)
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'de'), value=15.0)
Pandas(Index=('alice', 'us'), value=5.0)
```